# Picture box in External Datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder

We have Nested report in our application. and one of our report has picture box, So that should visible and invisible based on condition, when the row meets the particular condition.

How to show picture box for alternative rows (or for particular rows) in a External 
datawindow?.

Thanks
Ambat Bhath

Comment: do you have any problem with an expression on the `visible` property of the picture?

Comment: No, actually that picture box is placed in main report.